# Get list of files, without subdirectories

Tags: r

I want to get the list of files in a directory, but drop any subdirectories completely. list.files has the option include.dirs but forces it to be TRUE when recursive is FALSE.

I dont want files in subdirectories, and I dont want the names of the subdirectories. I want to be able to call:

```
list.files(recursive = F, include.dirs = F)
```

OS is Windows 7.1

Comment: What OS are you using?

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
list_files_only = function(...) {
    all_files = list.files(...)
    dirs = list.dirs(..., recursive = FALSE, full.names = FALSE)
    setdiff(all_files, dirs)
}
```

Works for the current working directory just fine, thanks to BenBarnes, should be able to pass through a `path` arg or other args.

Comment: Instead of using `gsub`, you could use `full.names = FALSE` when retrieving the list of directories.

Answer (score 1):

Using `assertive`:

```
library(assertive)
files <- dir()
files[!is_dir(files)]
```